# Что предпочесть: int x = arr.Lenth + strText.Append(x) или strText.Append(arr.Lenth)?

Tags: c#

Что предпочесть для вывода длины массива:

передать в переменную `int x = arr.Lenth`, и уже потом сделать `strText.Append(x);`

или обойтись без промежуточных этапов: `strText.Append(arr.Lenth);`

---

Проблема, если правильно понимаю, связана с уничтожением объектов сборщиком мусора. В первом случае в памяти останется только переменная `х`, во-втором - до момента вывода `arr.Length` массив будет находится в памяти. 
Или нет?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы бы сперва обозначили скоупы, в которых у вас находятся `arr` и вызов `strText.Append()`.

---

Предположим, они находятся внутри одно скоупа.

Есть один важный постулат о работе сборщика мусора:

> Время сборки объектов недетерминировано и зависит от реализации CLR

Этому есть куча причин, в которые для ответа вдаваться не нужно. Главное, что из этого постулата вытекает следующее: все потуги рассудить, какой вариант лучше, в общем-то бесполезны.

```
void Foo()
{
    int arr = new int[5];
    int x = arr.Length;    
    // какой-то длинный код
    strText.Append(x); // в этом месте память из-под arr еще может быть не освобождена!
}
```

Десктопная CLR, как правило, убирает объекты еще до выхода из скоупа, как только они становятся не нужны, поэтому *теоретически* переменная `x` имеет смысл.

---

Если переменные `arr` и вызов `strText.Append()` находятся в разных скоупах, время между заполнением массива и вызовом метода сильно неопределенное и на момент вызова метода массив уже давно не нужен, тогда сохранение длины массива тоже *теоретически* имеет смысл. Чуть больший, чем в первом случае :).

---

Почему *теоретически*? Во всех рассуждения об оптимизациях нужно руководствоваться только практикой. Как говорил классик: "Преждевременная оптимизация -- корень всех зол". Поэтому подобные вещи стоит принимать во внимание только когда "припрет": приложение начнет потреблять много памяти, процесс начнет много времени проводить в GC и т.д. Вот тогда берем в руки профайлер, смотрим на неоптимальные участки кода и вносим исправления. А до тех пор подобные вопросы имеют чисто теоретическую направленность.

Comment: +1, но @pontekorvo добавлю, что оптимизатор имеет право разрезать на части код `strText.Append(arr.Lenth);` и передвинуть эти части как ему вздумается. Например, утащить вычисленное значение `arr.Lenth` в начало функции. Поэтому не стоит пытаться соптимизировать за оптимизатор, он это сделает лучше.

Comment: @VladD не знал. А где почитать про это можно?

Comment: Хм. Поискал в гугле, не нашёл. Насколько я понимаю, оптимизатор имеет право передвигать части кода, если при этом смысл программы не меняется **с точки зрения потока, в котором бежит код**. То есть например он имеет право переставить операторы `x = 5; xIsInitialized = true;`.

Answer (score 4):

1) На всех семинарах по C# неоднократно говорилось, что код вида:

```
   int x = 3;
   int y = x * 2;
```

оптимизатором превращается в код

```
 int y = 3 * 2;
```

выбрасывая х вообще.

2) Давайте подумаем логически. Код

```
int x = arr.Length;    
// какой-то длинный код, очень, очень, очень длинный код, на 1 500 000 строк
strText.Append(x);
```

зачем оптимизатору держать в памяти, все 1 500 000 строк кода, переменную х?
Если он это может вычислить в нужной точке

```
strText.Append(arr.Length);
```

Вариант, когда внутри этих 1 500 000 строчек кода меняется длина arr не рассматривается, потому-что хранение переменной x тогда вообще не имеет смысла.

3) Конструкция типа

```
 int x = arr.Length;    
// какой-то длинный код
strText.Append(x);
```

имеет право быть, в режиме Debug если Вам нужно посмотреть что происходит с длиной массива (х). В режиме Release оптимизатор ее выбросит (х).

P.S. А чего Вы так боитесь сборщика мусора? У меня была прога, которая обрабатывала 90 000 000 записей базы и работала всю ночь каждый день. И ни разу сборщик ничего нужного не удалил...

Comment: (2) оптимизатор не реордерит строчки настолько эффективно, насколько я знаю.да и не должен - это продлит время жизни массива (объекта в куче), ради жизни int (4 байт в стеке), что вообще не логично.

Comment: @PashaPash да, действительно, я тут не прав наверное....не учел ситуацию когда между int x = arr.Length; и strText.Append(x); проходит много кода где arr не учавствует и не нужен...т.е. в ситуации  int x = arr.Length; arr.Dispose(); .......... strText.Append(x); действительно лучше хранить х чем весь массив. пардон :(

Comment: и, кстати, Array - не Disposable. а если бы и был - вызов Dispose не освобождает память.

Comment: я условно..... для наглядности...

Comment: я понимаю. топикастер может не понять :)

Comment: удалил... в комменте жалко не могу уже подправить...

Answer (score 2):

> передать в переменную int x = arr.Lenth, и уже потом сделать strText.Append(x);

Это имеет смысл делать только если

- массив достаточно большой (не пару тысяч элементов, а **действительно большой**).
- есть код код между `int x = arr.Lenth` и `strText.Append(x);` который выполняется достаточно долго (не пол секунды, а **действительно долго**).

Во всех остальных случаях - не будет никакой ощутимой разницы, делайте как вам удобнее.

Comment: Да, мои массивы немаленькие, и между этими вызовами есть куча кода.

Comment: тогда у вас ситуация, описанная в "только если".